# Call a mutator method from a separate class

Tags: java

I have a constructor class as so:

```
public class Student
{
    // Declare variables
    public int studentID;
    public String courseName;
    public int courseScore;
    public char courseGrade;

    // Default constructor
    public Student()
    {
       studentID = 1;
       courseName = "CIS 2085";
       courseScore = 89;
    }


    //========================================

    // Constructor with parameters
    public Student(int id, String course, int score)
    {
       setStud(id, course, score);
    }


    //========================================

    public String toString()
    {
       return (studentID + " " + courseName + " " + courseScore);
    }


    //========================================

    public void setStud(int id, String course, int score)
    {
       studentID = id;
       courseName = course;
       courseScore = score;
    }


     //========================================

    public int getStudentID()
    {
       return studentID;
    }


    //========================================

    public String getCourseName()
    {
       return courseName;
    }


    //========================================

    public int getCourseScore()
    {
       return courseScore;
    }


    //========================================

    public char getCourseGrade()
    {
       return courseGrade;
    }


    //========================================

    public static char calculateGrade(int courseScore)
    {
       if (courseScore >= 94)
           courseGrade = 'A';

       else if ((courseScore >= 85) && (courseScore <= 93))
           courseGrade = 'B';

       else if ((courseScore >= 75) && (courseScore <= 84))
           courseGrade = 'C';

       else if ((courseScore >= 65) && (courseScore <= 74))
           courseGrade = 'D';

       else
           courseGrade = 'F';

       return courseGrade;
    }

    //========================================

}
```

And I have my implementation class so far, like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StudentImplementation
{
    // Sllow 'console' to receive input from the user
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Method main
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Declare variables

        // Object 1: first. Uses the default constructor.
        Student first = new Student();

        //System.out.println(first);

        // Object 2: second.
        Student second = new Student(3, "Advanced Java Programming", 83);

        //System.out.println(second);

        // Use calculateGrade method to receive grade for object 1

        char grade = Student.calculateGrade(first.getCourseScore);
        System.out.println(grade);
    }
}
```

So I am trying to use my calculateGrade method to output the appropriate grade based on my objects courseScore.

The Student class is in a separate file from my implementation class.

When I run this program I receive the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Student.calculateGrade(I)C
    at StudentImplementation.main(StudentImplementation.java:27)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem? I don't see what is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're having. Can you not simply call the calculateGrade method?

Comment: I am trying to call the method CalculateGrade to work in my implementation file. so that it will take the courseScore of object 1 (first) and give me the courseGrade.

Comment: Yes, I am wondering how I call the method since it is in another class.

Comment: Its public, so just call it directly (ie: `first.calculateGrade()`). 2 things to note: methods in Java are always lower case, and you don't need the `char g` parameter in the method.

Comment: umm, i thought that the CalculateGrade method is in the Student class. That would be the logical place to put it. if not, then just pass declare the object of that class and pass in the coursescore to the function

Comment: In fact when you instanciate your Student (new Student()), it sort of *contains* the classes defined in the Student.class (ie calculateGrade()). So when you call first.calculateGrade() you call the method of your first student. This way it will use the courseScore of your first student. (second.calculateGrade() will use the attributes of the second student)

Comment: I updated my code to what it is currently at. Fundhor, I believe it was you who had two variations of code as to how to solve this issue.  I think you deleted one of them? If it wasn't you, sorry for the confusion.

My calculateGrade method is in a separate class from the implementation part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a cleaner version of your Student class that does what you want it to do. I've taken out the unnecessary variables and methods, and cleaned it up a bit.

The reason I did this is because right now, your code contains a lot of things that don't make sense (eg. adding a parameter to a method so you can set the parameters value in the method itself and then return it, using a setter method in your constructor).

```
public class Student {
    public int studentID;
    public String courseName;
    public int courseScore;

    public Student() {
        this(1, "CIS 2085", 89);
    }

    public Student(int id, String course, int score) {
        this.studentID = id;
        this.courseName = course;
        this.courseScore = score;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return studentID + " " + courseName + " " + courseScore;
    }

    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public int getCourseScore() {
        return courseScore;
    }


    public char getCourseGrade() {
        if (courseScore >= 94) {
            return 'A';
        } else if (courseScore >= 85 && courseScore <= 93) {
            return 'B';
        } else if (courseScore >= 75 && courseScore <= 84) {
            return 'C';
        } else if (courseScore >= 65 && courseScore <= 74) {
            return 'D';
        }
        return 'E';
    }

}
```

Here's an example implementation to go along with that:

```
public class StudentImplementation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student first = new Student(); //default constructor
        System.out.println(first.getCourseGrade());
        Student second = new Student(3, "Advanced JAVA Programming", 83);
        System.out.println(second.getCourseGrade());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering what the this. function does? I have never heard of that before.

Comment: this refers to the object that called the function. so when we do first.getCourseGrade(), this refers to the 'first' object

Comment: `this` refers to the current instance of the object. For example your `Student` class, each `Student` object contains the course grade, course name and student ID. That means there can be multiple instances of the `Student` object each having their own values- the `this` keyword helps the Java compiler know how to differentiate between them. Here's some more documentation by Oracle if you want more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. So the program compiles, but it outputs 0000 for the grade. Do you know why that would be happening?

Comment: Sorry, I had some errors in the `Student` class code. Replace it again and run it again- I just tested it on my side, and it worked: http://i.imgur.com/UK9N6fT.png

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. One last question. What is the @Override for?

Comment: `@Override` is an annotation that indicates that the method under the annotation is being overridden from a superclass. What that means is that, the implementation of the method is different than what it was from the super class. Whenever a class extends a class or implements an interface, the methods and values of that class become accessible by the subclass (the class that is extending/implementing). Now you might say, "But my Student class isn't extending anything? How can it be overriding a method?" cont.

Comment: That is because all objects in java implicitly extend object, and every object contains some standard methods like toString(), getHashCode(), equals() etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help with this. I got it sorted out, and learned something new!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Change your calculateGrade method to:

```
public char calculateGrade() {
    courseScore = this.getCourseScore(); // This refers to the student
                                         // from whom you called the
                                         // calculaGrade() method -->
                                         // first.calculateGrade()
    if (courseScore >= 94) {
        courseGrade = 'A';
    } else if ((courseScore >= 85) && (courseScore <= 93)) {
        courseGrade = 'B';
    } else if ((courseScore >= 75) && (courseScore <= 84)) {
        courseGrade = 'C';
    } else if ((courseScore >= 65) && (courseScore <= 74)) {
        courseGrade = 'D';
    } else {
        courseGrade = 'F';
    }
    return courseGrade;
}
```

Then just use first.calculateGrade(). And print the result:

```
Student first = new Student();
char firstStudentGrade = first.calculateGrade();
System.out.println(firstStudentGrade);
```

PS: method names do not start with capital letters ;)

Comment: if the object has been initialized, then it should give the correct value of the attribute.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Student.calculateGrade()C
 at StudentImplementation.main(StudentImplementation.java:25)

That is what I receive when I try that.

Comment: Did you change the method CalculateGrade(char g) to calculateGrade() in your Student class ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public char CalculateGrade()
{
    if (this.courseScore >= 94)
        courseGrade = 'A';

    else if ((this.courseScore >= 85) && (this.courseScore <= 93))
        courseGrade = 'B';

    else if ((this.courseScore >= 75) && (this.courseScore <= 84))
        courseGrade = 'C';

    else if ((this.courseScore >= 65) && (this.courseScore <= 74))
        courseGrade = 'D';

    else
        courseGrade = 'F';

    g = courseGrade;

    return g;
}
```

And call it as:

```
System.out.println(first.CalculateGrade());
```

Comment: This is the error I get when I enter that:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Student.CalculateGrade()C
 at StudentImplementation.main(StudentImplementation.java:25)

Comment: and in the default constructor, course score is 89.

Comment: where have you defined the CalculateGrade() method

Comment: can you please try to put the method exactly as i have described? please place it in the Student class. would that be allowed?

Comment: I did, I tried retyping it, and copy & pasting. I still get that same error.

Comment: hmm. can you please share the entire code for your Student class and Main class? please put that as an edit in your question.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your `Student` object, simply call your method...

```
Student first = new Student();
first.CalculateGrade();
```

And remove the `g` parameter from `CalculateGrade(char gg)`. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the statement

```
char grade = Student.calculateGrade(first.getCourseScore);
```

to

```
char grade = Student.calculateGrade(first.getCourseScore());
```

You missed the `()` during the method call.